# vulnerable getlogin

Tags: appsec, linux, source-code, unix, c

I was reading "[A taxonomy of Coding Errors](https://www.fortify.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/index.html)" and I have a doubt regarding the point mentioned in C/C++ >> API Abuse >> Often Misused: Authentication(getlogin).

I fail to understand the attack vector mentioned there. To quote a statement -

> The getlogin() function is supposed to return a string containing the name of the user currently logged in at the terminal, but an attacker can cause getlogin() to return the name of any user logged in to the machine.

How does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getlogin()` works by checking a property of stdin.  However, a malicious attacker can start your program with stdin redirected to some other user's controlling terminal, and that will fool `getlogin()`.

Don't use `getlogin()` for security purposes.  You'll want to look at `getuid()`, `geteuid()`, `getpwuid()`, and similar methods.

Comment: thanks for the answer, looking at the source code gave me a clearer idea.

Answer (score 5):

The **first** problem is that it's not threadsafe, and the string buffer that is used doesn't contain a trustworthy value; i.e., you can't be sure the value you get back is any good. US-CERT goes into some detail.

> The results of getlogin() should not be trusted.
>
> The getlogin() function returns a pointer to a string that contains
>   the name of the user associated with the calling process. The function
>   is not reentrant, meaning that if it is called from another process,
>   the contents are not locked out and the value of the string can be
>   changed by another process. This makes it very risky to use because
>   the username can be changed by other processes, so the results of the
>   function cannot be trusted.

US-CERT has [more details on the issue](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding/752-BSI.html). One alternative is to use the threadsafe version getlogin_r(), or to use other mechanisms.

The **second** problem is that t[here is a known flaw in SSH that allows attackers to specifically spoof the result of getlogin()](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/740619):

> On platforms relying on getlogin() (mainly the different BSD variants)
>   malicious users can at least send misleading messages to syslog and
>   others applications (getlogin() call will return "root").

[Rapid7 has additional details](http://www.rapid7.com/vulndb/lookup/ssh-sshinc-getlogin-spoof-privilege-escalation) as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, looking at the source code gave me a clearer idea.